# Word difference between 'flap' and 'flutter'

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between **flap** and **flutter**?

e.g.:

> The bird is flapping its wings.
>
> The bird is fluttering its wings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Etymologically, the verb **to flap** is related to the noun **flap**. A *flap* is something that hangs free at one end, and is fixed at the other. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flap):

> something that is broad, limber, or flat and usually thin and that hangs loose or projects freely: such as
>
> a :  a piece on a garment that hangs free
>
> b :  a part of a book jacket that folds under the book's cover
>
> c :  a piece of tissue partly severed from its place of origin for use in surgical grafting
>
> d :  an extended part forming the closure (as of an envelope or carton)

The act of moving this loose end up and down along its join is *flapping*, perhaps onomatopoeic from the resultant sound.

A *flutter* is a very light and rapid flapping motion. Speed and agility distinguish a flutter from a flap. You might say that a hummingbird or a butterfly *flutters* its wings, since both of those are small and agile creatures with rapid wing motions.

Technically, you could also say that the hummingbird flies by *flapping* its wings, since the fluttering is accomplished by moving its wing up and down, i.e., by flapping. However, the swiftness and relative quietness of the motion makes *flutter* the more usual choice. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hummingbird%20fluttering%2C%20hummingbird%20flapping&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chummingbird%20fluttering%3B%2Cc0) shows ***zero*** results for "hummingbird flapping" as opposed to "hummingbird fluttering".

But you would not say an eagle or a hawk *flutters* its wings. You would say *flap*, because the movement is too slow to qualify as a flutter. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Eagle%20fluttering%2Ceagle%20flapping&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceagle%20flapping%3B%2Cc0) again shows zero results for "eagle fluttering" as opposed to "eagle flapping".

A sail that's *fluttering* in the wind is moving rather more quickly and quietly than one that's *flapping*. Leaves *flutter* in the breeze; they do not *flap*.

Answer (score 0):

**Flap** in this case emphasizes an effective motion.

- A bird flies by flapping its wings.

**Flutter** hints that something ineffective is happening.

The bird had a broken wing. Try as it might fluttering them, it could not fly.

The site Wikidiff provides an extensive page, [What is the difference between flap and flutter?](http://wikidiff.com/flutter/flap) You can often find answers to questions like this simply by typing the two words into a search engine. I typed **flap flutter** into Google, and that link was listed first.

Comment: *flutter* does not necessarily indicate ineffectiveness. The site you link to specifically has "A bird flutters its wings" as an example. And one wouldn't typically say a butterfly flaps its wings.

Comment: @verbose True. I wanted to avoid the dreaded "just a link answer* criticism, but provide enough direct information that was not just a copy of what the other site said.  In "A bird flutters its wings.", I do not interpret that to mean it is flying. It brings to my mind a baby bird just moving its wings while still in the nest. For insects and hummingbirds, **flutter** and **fly** are indeed directly linked, perhaps because the speed of wing motion is very quick. Still, [butterfly flap and fly](http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?782595) occurs without seeming awkward.